# Multiple flask_dropzone in one page

Tags: python-3.x, flask, file-upload, dropzone.js, flask-uploads

I'm a new dev.

I have multiple steps form and I want to allow users to upload Max of 2 ( for e.g. DROPZONE_MAX_FILE_SIZE= 3, PLOADED_PATH=os.path.join(base, 'doc Form'))

then at a different section (step) of the form I want to allow user to upload more files with different config ( for e.g. DROPZONE_MAX_FILE_SIZE= 20, PLOADED_PATH=os.path.join(base, 'med'))

Things I've tried :

1 -  tried to insert dropzone on the same forms twice in two different Div and provided custom options for each including different URL route but didn't work ( only works when I remove one of them) I always get error `SECOND_PATH_URL_OR_FUNCTION is not defined`

2 - after reading this answer [Multiple Dropzone in a single page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26657489/multiple-dropzone-in-a-single-page) I've replaced div with form and added custom options where every dropzone have it's own function in flask

If I removed `DROPZONE_UPLOAD_ACTION='handle_upload'` from the app config and added as a custom option I get this error on chrome's console `No URL provided.`

When I add one of the URL, it's the only one that have chance to work because I get error for the second one `handle_upload2 is not defined` where handle_upload2 is just a duplicate from the original function that's called handle_upload which i have added it's url in the config options .

It seems as if custom_options doesn't overRide app.config details

I'm close but I don't know how to add both URL in the same page so I can run one function script `onclick` and send all data in an Ajax as if they were one form.

flask file current app config options  :

```
UPLOADED_PATH=os.path.join(basedir, 'uploads'),
# Flask-Dropzone config:
DROPZONE_ALLOWED_FILE_TYPE='image',
DROPZONE_MAX_FILE_SIZE=3,
DROPZONE_MAX_FILES=30,
DROPZONE_IN_FORM=True,
DROPZONE_UPLOAD_ON_CLICK=True,
DROPZONE_UPLOAD_ACTION='handle_upload',  # URL or endpoint
DROPZONE_UPLOAD_BTN_ID='uploadID',
```

custom options for Drop Zone 1 :

```
    {{ dropzone.config(custom_init='dz = this;document.getElementById("uploadID").addEventListener("click", function handler(e) {dz.processQueue();});',
                 custom_options='autoProcessQueue: false, addRemoveLinks: true, maxFiles: 2,DROPZONE_UPLOAD_ACTION:handle_upload,') }}
```

and for drop Zone 2 :

```
{{ dropzone.config(custom_init='dz2 = this;document.getElementById("uploadID").addEventListener("click", function handler(e) {dz2.processQueue();});',
                     custom_options='autoProcessQueue: false, addRemoveLinks: true, maxFiles: 2,DROPZONE_UPLOAD_ACTION:handle_upload2,') }}
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: i'll keep that in my mind thxx

Answer (score 1):

Flask-drop-zone documentation say:
You may want to use different configuration for multiple drop area on different pages, in this case, you can pass the specific keyword arguments into `dropzone.config()` directly.

The keyword arguments should mapping the corresponding conflagration variable in this way:

`DROPZONE_DEFAULT_MESSAGE` –> default_message
`DROPZONE_TIMEOUT` –> timeout
`DROPZONE_ALLOWED_FILE_TYPE` –> allowed_file_type
etc
example:

```
{{ dropzone.config(max_files=10, timeout=10000, default_message='Drop here!') }}
```

The keyword argument you pass will overwrite the corresponding configurations.

---

So, i think you can't make different configuration for many drop-zones in the same page.

but you can send two URL for different drop-zones in the same page:

```
{{ dropzone.create(action= url_for('product.first_upload')) }}
{{ dropzone.create(action= url_for('product.second_upload')) }}

@product.route('/first_upload', methods=['POST'])
def first_upload():
    #do something

@product.route('/second_upload', methods=['POST'])
def second_upload():
    #do something
```

---

Also, you can send argument's to the upload function, to differ between drop-zones:

```
@product.route('/upload_images/<string:upload_for><int:id>', methods=['POST'])
def upload_images(upload_for, id):
    if upload_for == "Something like Cat Image":
        #do something with id passed
```

Comment: thanks alot man , you know 2 days ago i dropped flask-dropzone and replaced it with dropzon.js . its harder but i can do as many configurations as i want now .