# Upload Images with multiple Dropzone JS in a single Form

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, dropzone.js

I created a repeater form together with dropzone JS. Now the repeater is fine, able to POST to DB. The problem now is the Image Upload part. So since the problem is the Image upload part, I created a test form where I click the "Add" button and the dropzone will just duplicate itself inside. When I upload, it's successful but it only uploads the last dropzone I uploaded in. I'm using PHP Codeigniter Framework for this.

The question is, how can I like split those uploads, for example, Dropzone1 uploads to folder 123, Dropzone2 uploads to folder 987, etc.. in 1 single POST form

My `HTML` and `JS` Code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Image Test Page</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Test Image Form</h2>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="addTest">Add</button>
  <form action="admin/testInsert" method="post">
    

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="name">Name:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Enter email" name="name[]">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="Enter password" name="pwd[]">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="desc">Description:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="desc" placeholder="Enter password" name="desc[]">
    </div>
    <div id="testDiv">
        <div class="mb-3">
        <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-lg-3 col-form-label">Images</label>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
         <div class="dropzone dropzone-default dropzone-primary" id="kt_dropzone_1">
          <div class="dropzone-msg dz-message needsclick">
            <h3 class="dropzone-msg-title">Drop files here or click to upload.</h3>
            <span class="dropzone-msg-desc">Upload up to 6 files</span>
          </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>

    </div>
    <button type="submit" id="subBtn" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>

</body>
</html>

<script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function(){      

            var i= 1;

         $('#addTest').click(function(){  
               i++;

               //$('#testDiv').append('</br><div id="row'+i+'"><h3 class="font-size-lg text-dark font-weight-bold mb-6">2. Product Detail Media:</h3><div class="mb-3"><div class="form-group"><div class="col-lg-6"><div class="dropzone dropzone-default dropzone-primary" id="kt_dropzone_'+i+'"><div class="dropzone-msg dz-message needsclick"><h3 class="dropzone-msg-title">Drop files here or click to upload.</h3><span class="dropzone-msg-desc">Upload up to 6 files</span></div></div></div></div></div><button type="button" name="remove" id="'+i+'" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove">X</button> </div> ');
                $('#testDiv').append('<div class="form-group"><label for="email">Email:</label><input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email" name="name[]"></div>');
               $('#testDiv').append('<div class="form-group"><label for="pwd">Description:</label><textarea type="text" class="form-control" id="desc" placeholder="Enter desc" name="desc[]" ></textarea></div>');
               $('#testDiv').append('<div class="form-group"><label for="pwd">Password:</label><input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="Enter password" name="pwd[]"></div>');

               $('#testDiv').append('<div class="mb-3"><div class="form-group"><label class="col-lg-3 col-form-label">Images</label><div class="col-lg-6"><div class="dropzone dropzone-default dropzone-primary" id="kt_dropzone_'+i+'"><div class="dropzone-msg dz-message needsclick"><h3 class="dropzone-msg-title">Drop files here or click to upload.</h3><span class="dropzone-msg-desc">Upload up to 6 files</span></div></div></div></div></div>');


               console.log(i);

               var myDropzone = new Dropzone('#kt_dropzone_'+i+'',{
                    //url: "admin/upload_file", // Set the url for your upload script location
                    url: "admin/testUpload",
                    paramName: "file", // The name that will be used to transfer the file
                    uploadMultiple: true,
                    maxFiles: 6,
                    maxFilesize: 2, // MB
                    parallelUploads: 10,
                    addRemoveLinks: true,
                    autoProcessQueue: false,
                    acceptedFiles: "image/*",
                    accept: function(file, done) {
                        if (file.name == "justinbieber.jpg") {
                            done("Naha, you don't.");
                        } else {
                            done();
                        }
                    }
                }); 

               $('#subBtn').on('click', function () {
                myDropzone.processQueue();
            });

          });
          
        }); 

        
    </script>
```

Controller Code

```
public function testUpload(){
        $this->Admin_model->test();
    }
```

Code for upload in Model

```
function test(){

        $prodDetID = $this->session->tempdata('item');

        $this->load->library('ftp');

        $config['hostname'] = '127.0.0.1';
        $config['username'] = 'root';
        $config['password'] = '';
        $config['debug']    = TRUE;

        $this->ftp->connect($config);

        foreach($prodDetID as $val){
            if(!is_dir('./upload/assets/ProductDetail/'.$val))
            {
            mkdir('./upload/assets/ProductDetail/'.$val,077,TRUE);

            }
            $num_files = count($_FILES['file']['name']);
            
            for($i = 0; $i < $num_files; $i++){
              $img = pathinfo($_FILES['file']['name'][$i], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
              $imgName = $val."".date('YmdHis').'.'.$img;
              $test = $this->ftp->upload($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i], "upload/assets/ProductDetail/$val/".$_FILES['file']['name'][$i], 'auto');
          }

        }
        $this->session->unset_tempdata('item');

        
    }
```

The image below is the output for the View
[image]

When submit button is clicked, the based insert id is 29 and 30. Folder 29 and 30 is created. As seen in the picture below, both folders it has the same uploaded image.
[image]

Any help/advice would be appreciated. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: How does your code know in which directory the image belongs?   You can use params to give the upload script info where to save the image.  From the documentation:   __Dropzone will submit any hidden fields you have in your dropzone form. So this is an easy way to submit additional data. You can also use the params option.__

Comment: @AlexanderDobernig In the Model, the image taken will be stored in folders created based on some random ID generated everytime something is created. The problem now, is that is it possible to identify or specify different dropzones. For example DZ 1 has 2 img and DZ 2 has 5 img. When submitted, the images will be stored in Folders 123 and 987 respectively where the folders are freshly created from random generated id

Comment: You mean   "The problem now, __IT IS NOT POSSIBLE??__

Comment: Please see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26657489/multiple-dropzone-in-a-single-page

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @AlexanderDobernig. After some discussion with my colleagues, which they pointed out what I wanted is very ambitious and decided that we should just limit the append and just do the dropzones 1 by 1.

Comment: Ok this will work best ;-). Add your solution as answer and accept it so that it is clear, that the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, question I asked is very ambitious so I will stick with a simpler method of implementing the uploads. So I will be sticking with using the example given by @AlexanderDobernig

Link Suggested [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26657489/multiple-dropzone-in-a-single-page/26657663)